# How to use SOAP 1.2 with a different Content-Type in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I need to communicate via SOAP with an application that was bought from another company. The wsdl we received is for SOAP 1.2 and the same is stated in the minimalistic technical documentation. However every request produces the following error:

> Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. [415]

According to the supplier their software was reprogrammed to use SOAP 1.2 with the content-type from SOAP 1.1 (text/xml; charset=utf-8). I'm using Spring Boot with the WebServiceGatewaySupport. The SoapMessageFactory is configured to use SOAP 1.2 which (as expected) sets the content-type to 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8':

```
@Bean(name = "mySoapMessageFactory")
public SaajSoapMessageFactory saajSoapMessageFactory() throws SOAPException {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory saajSoapMessageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL));
    saajSoapMessageFactory.setSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_12);

    return saajSoapMessageFactory;
}
```

In the long run the company which supplied the SOAP endpoint should fix their software to honor the standards. But until then I am looking for a quick fix since the data needs to be tested...

What I tried so far:
1) Change the content-type header with a WebServiceMessageCallback. Results in the same error as the content-type seems to be switched back to the SOAP 1.2 default before the request is sent.

```
public GetOrganisationUnitDataResponse getOrganisationUnitDataResponse(Integer skip) {
    //SNIP

    GetOrganisationUnitDataResponse response = (GetOrganisationUnitDataResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(getOrganisationUnitData, getWebServiceMessageCallback());

    //SNIP

    return response;
}

private WebServiceMessageCallback getWebServiceMessageCallback() {
    return webServiceMessage -> {
        SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)webServiceMessage;
        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
        headers.setHeader(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        headers.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    };
}
```

2) ClientInterceptor modifying the SaajSoapMessage. Same modification as in point 1) with the same result.

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    WebServiceMessage request = messageContext.getRequest();
    SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)request;
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
    headers.removeHeader("Content-Type");
    headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    return true;
}
```

3) ClientInterceptor modifying the TransportContext. This results in a http 400 Bad Request.

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
    HttpComponentsConnection connection =(HttpComponentsConnection) context.getConnection();
    connection.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    return true;
}
```

Is there a 'proper' Spring Boot way to modify the content-type?

Comment: Hi did you find any solutions for this yet?